Bounced email without return-path notifies back without the bounce detail
I'm sending a lot of emails and therefore I receive some bounced email notifications. I wanted to change the email address that receives those bounce emails.
In the first setting, the bounce emails were sent to the sender of the email (sender@email.com) and it looks like this:
An error occurred while trying to deliver the mail to the following recipients:
aaa@a.fr
Reporting-MTA: dns; b224-51.smtp-out.eu-central-1.amazonses.com

Action: failed
Final-Recipient: rfc822; aaa@a.fr
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 4.4.7 Message expired: unable to deliver in 840 minutes.<421 4.4.1 Failed to establish connection>
Status: 4.4.7



----- Original message -----
From:sender@email.com
To:aaa@a.fr
CC:null
Date:Sat, 9 Nov 2024 12:00:20 +0000
Subject:mySubject

contentEmail

When setting the return-path header to other@email.com I receive the bounce email, but the content is different:
An error occurred while trying to deliver the mail to the following recipients:
aaa@a.fr


---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: sender@email.com
To: aaa@a.fr
Cc: 
Bcc: 
Date: 
Subject: mySubject

contentEmail

I'm losing the reason of the bounce.
I can access the reason of the bounce via SNS but then I'll receive 2 emails per bounce.
How can I enrich the email with the bounce reason? Or how can I disable the bounced notification so I can use the SNS instead?
